# Removing a trailing character at the end of a URL using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server

I have a url:
www.example.com/tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-teal/

I need it to change to

www.example.com/ink-wineberry/

so far I have

the following in my htaccess as a temporary fix

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ink
RewriteRule -1oz/ /ink [R=301,L]
```

edit* to make it simpler here are a few more examples

tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-teal-1oz/ should be tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-teal/

tattoo-ink-radiant-super-white-1oz/ should be tattoo-ink-radiant-super-white/

Comment: Is `ink-wineberry` a dynamic text or static one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-1oz/?$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks but i need something more dynamic. I have multiple products which would need to change from tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-wineberry-1oz/ to tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-wineberry/ or tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-teal-1oz/ to tattoo-ink-radiant-colors-teal/