# Remove these characters at the end of the url using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
http://www.example.com/marketplace/seller/profile/swamytiles?___
```

This is the URL. i want to remove those **?___** characters in the above url, using .htaccess url rewrite.

I tried this [Removing a trailing character at the end of a URL using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435578/removing-a-trailing-character-at-the-end-of-a-url-using-htaccess). but it didn't help me. please someone guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]+)\?___ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Please any one suggest a best guide to learn how to write rewrite rules. Thank you.